# Volitional: 見せましょう does not mean "let's have a look"?

Tags: volitional-form

> 部下：すみません、部長。この書類、見ていただけませんか。
>   部長：
>   1. ご覧になってください。
>   2. 会議のあとならいいですよ。
>   3. すぐに見せましょう。

Source: [Japanesetest4you](http://japanesetest4you.com/japanese-language-proficiency-test-jlpt-n3-listening-exercise-5/)

Option 1 means, "Please have a look," using the honorific equivalents of **見る** and **くれる**. This does not fit the context.

Option 2 is the given answer, to which I have no objection. However, I feel that option 3 is also a viable choice, because **見せる** means **to show something**. Saying **見せましょう** seems to me like the **部長** is allowing the **部下** to show them the **書類**. I think this can be thus translated into English: **Let's have a look right away then!**

If my understanding of this usage of the volitional form is correct, why is option 3 not correct?

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

見せましょう would literally translate to "Let's show it (to someone else)!"

So it's not something that a boss would say to a subordinate who is trying to ask them to look at something.

Possibly 見ましょう could be said by a boss at this point, though that seems a bit too relaxed a response, it would translate to "Let's look (at it) (together). However, since the subordinate is asking the boss to check something, in theory because his authority is needed, or his input is what is valued, there is little reason for him to suggest looking at it together with the subordinate.

Comment: I see! If so, is there not a better way of saying "let's have a look then" in Japanese? I'm thinking, if the 部下 and 部長 are on friendly terms, this response seems appropriate in real life (at least the English one). Would you kindly suggest a good way to say this? Thank you!

Comment: Literally, if the Japanese boss and the subordinate were on as friendly terms as you suggest, then じゃ、見ましょう（か）。 would in fact be fine. It's just that "Let's have a look, then." is a very un-Japanese sort of thing to say. ^_^

Comment: `見ましょう ... would translate to "Let's look (at it) (together) ...  there is little reason for him to suggest looking at it together with the subordinate.` <-- 見ましょう can mean "I'll look (at it)". 「すぐに見ましょう。」"I'll have a look at it right now." would be a natural response. `見せましょう would literally translate to "Let's show it (to someone else)` <-- 見せましょう can mean "I'll show you." 「すぐに見せましょう。」"I'll show it to you right now."

Answer (score 2):

～～ましょう (or ～う・よう in casual form) can mean either "I'll ~~" or "Let's ~~".

＃2 すぐに見**せ**ましょう would mean either "I'll show it to you right away" or "Let's show it to [someone else] right away", so it cannot be a correct response.

すぐに見ましょう can mean "I'll have a look at it right away", so this could be a correct response. It can also mean "Let's look at it (together) right away" depending on the context.